# How do I stop Group Policy applied to an OU from being inherited by a Sub OUs?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have an **OU** "**Check**" and another **OU** "**subCheck**". I am applying Group policy to the **Check** **OU**. It should not affect the sub **OU**. What can I do to accomplish this? I tried to disable the ***inherited from parent check box*** in the **security settings** of the sub OU. But still the sub OU users are getting affected by the Group policy applied to the parent. please provide me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To block inheritance from parent GPO's scoped to parrent OU's, you need to **Block Inheritance**.

To do so, navigate to the OU in the left pane tree view of the GPMC console, right-click the appropriate OU (in your case, "subCheck") and check the "**Block Inheritance**" option. This will only block GPO's that are not ***enforced***. Don't modify the security settings on the OU

Comment: Thanks a lot Mathias. I am new to AD. So please don't hesitate to clear my doubts whatever silly they may be. I have another doubt of how to create a shadow group and what is the actual purpose of it. Can you help me with that?

Comment: No problem. As a general rule of thumb - "If you don't know what it is, you probably don't need it". But if you're facing an actual problem with it, ask a new question :-)